# Adding a-axis with live editor of amcharts

Tags: label, axis, amcharts

I have a very simple question but unfortunately I could not find anything related to my problem.

I just want to know how can I add an x-axis or y-axis label in live editor of amcharts? By default, only y-axis is shown with live editor of a chart. I tried to use 'Value axes' from the menu on the left but the created label was overlapped with the existing y-axis label rather than appear on the x-axis. Also, I could not change the position of axis label through the 'Position' property of 'Value axes'.

Please help.

Mushi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For x axis - select "CategoryAxis" and enter "title" in "General Settings". Similar with value axis - select your value axis in the menu and enter title in general settings.